# PHP Get Web page size including images, css & javascript

Tags: php, jquery, html

I'm trying to get a total size of a page including images, CSS & javascript.

I've noticed a few things flying round like a curl request and then using the curl_info to show how much data this has downloaded... This works OK but it doesn't include all images, CSS & javascript.

```
$curl = curl_init('http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-2844384/It-s-mini-adventure-Astonishing-moment-frustrated-passengers-lift-Mini-way-tram-driver-parked-car-tracks.html');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_exec($curl);
//get the download size of page
print("Download size: " . curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_SIZE_DOWNLOAD) .'<br>');
```

This returns 381.285 kb yet tools.pingdom.com returns over 5MB.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: your curl is only getting the easy part, the html. You would have to process all the resource files referenced within that html as well. Look into using a headless browser

Comment: Something like phantomjs??

Answer (score 0):

if via curl you just can see the page, you must get each image, css & javascript, example you use preg_match each rel, src, etc
example:

```
$pattern = '/src="(.*)" /';
preg_match($pattern, substr($subject,3), $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
getcurlsize($matches[1][0]);
```

$subject is the page content you have been got

getcurlsize is function you must created to get curl file size info